# Minimum Number of Variables required to represent any 4 points in Cartesian Co-Ordinates?

Tags: analytic-geometry

The points are guaranteed to be the vertices of some orthogonally oriented rectangle.

A trivial solution to problem is to use 8 variables, Two for each point. A better solution is to use 4 values, namely x , y co-ordinates of the center of the rectangle of those 4 points, the width and the height of the rectangle.
But can we go lower? or Can we prove otherwise that 4 is the minimum?

Comment: Depends what you are looking for.  If you want to , you can include all $8$ values in a single binary string.  Not a very pleasant way to describe points, but still.

Comment: Are they guaranteed to be the vertices of some orthogonally oriented rectangle? If so, you should mention this (if not, your approach doesn't seem to work...)

Comment: Not sure how to word this but creating a composite variable with all 8 values is not what I'm looking for. 

Yes, They should be guaranteed to be the vertices of some orthogonally oriented rectangle. Thanks for pointing it out! I'll update it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Orthogonally oriented" = "axis-oriented"? Problem is 2D? Then coordinates are $(a,b)$, $(a+l,b)$, $(a,b+w)$, $(a+l,b+w)$. You can change any one of numbers $a$, $b$, $l$, $w$ without changing remaining 3 numbers, then 4 real numbers is minimum necessary information to describe 4 points coordinates.